# Error message 'database is locked' with Subversion server accessing repository through SMB

Tags: database, svn, smb, post-commit, nas

I created a Subversion server using a NAS and a Raspberry Pi. The Pi runs the server, and has an SMB share from the NAS mounted, on which the repository is stored.

(A setup without using both devices is not an option as the NAS has no option to install subversion and the Pi has not enough storage capacity.)

When I commit, I get the following error message on the client:

```
error message:
Warning: post commit FS processing had error:
database is locked, executing statement 'COMMIT TRANSACTION;'
```

What does this error message mean? Is there a way to avoid this problem? The system seems to work fine at first sight - is there a risk this will my subversion checkout or worse, Subversion server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try add `enable-rep-sharing = false` to  to SVNREPOS/db/fsfs.conf. This option disables `representation sharing feature` that uses SQLite database internally. SQLite known to have some issues when stored on network share.